# Ember sidebar - returning from "admin" sidebar to "normal"

Tags: ember.js

My application route defines my sidebar as follows (`routes/application.js`):

```
renderTemplate: function() {

    this.render();

    // sidebar
    this.render("partials/sidebar", {
        outlet: "sidebar",
        into: "application" // important when using at root level
    });
}
```

When the user enters the admin area of the app, there is a special admin sidebar which is applied as follows (`routes/settings.js`):

```
renderTemplate: function() {

    this.render();

    // sidebar
    this.render("partials/sidebaradmin", {
        outlet: "sidebar",
        into: "application" // important when using at root level
    });
}
```

This works as you would expect. However, when leaving the settings area, the sidebar becomes blank.

What is the correct way to ensure that regardless of where the user transitions to, that the standard sidebar redraws?

Comment: Can you recreate this in emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: can you show your templates?

Comment: reproduced http://emberjs.jsbin.com/poquyo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: opened an issue https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written an addon that I'm using in some of my apps which helps with this:

https://github.com/minutebase/ember-render-stack

Comment: Cool! So, is this a bug in the framework that should be fixed? It feels weird to have an addon for the behavior that should just work...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this using a component instead of named outlet, so just wanted to cross-reference that here if someone will benefit from it

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27846034/908842