# Restoring content in outlet set on the ApplicationRoute

Tags: ember.js

I have an application route that is rendering a template into an outlet named 'sidebar', this should be viewable across the whole of the app. I have set up a quick example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ziwabi/1/edit?html,js,output).

When I go into one of the routes (in my example, the color route) this outlet will render a different template and when you navigate to another route in the app it should show the sidebar that was there originally.

This doesn't happen automatically and I understand it is because once the `ApplciationRoute` has been entered which is when the app is first loaded the `renderTemplate` is called and not called again until page refresh. This makes sense to me, but I'm unsure how to get around this.

I have tried re-calling the `Route#render` method again under the `willTransition` action of the `ColorRoute` but it doesn't work.

```
...
actions: {
    willTransition: function() {
        this.render('color.sidebar', { 
            into: 'application', 
            outlet: 'sidebar' 
        });
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came up with another "workaround" for this using a component instead of a named outlet.

Instead of `{{ outlet "sidebar" }}` in your `application` template just use `{{ x-sidebar }}`

Then, define the `x-sidebar` component template as follows:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/x-sidebar">
    {{partial sidebar }}
  </script>
```

So, now your newly created component is expecting a `sidebar` property to tell it which template to display.

You can pass that property when you use the component like so:

```
{{ x-sidebar sidebar=sidebar }}
```

Then, you can use `activate/deactivate` hooks in your routes to set the `sidebar` property on the `application` controller, for example:

```
App.ColorRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return params.color;
  },

  activate: function(){
    this.controllerFor('application').set('sidebar', 'color/sidebar');
  },  
  deactivate: function(){
    this.controllerFor('application').set('sidebar', 'sidebar');
  }  

});
```

Working solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cuzuxu/3/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: This looks like a good solution for the most part, however I will need the sidebar to display data about the model that is shown (e.g. the selected colour). I don't think I can get the model data in the activate hook?

Comment: True, but you can always pass that in from `afterModel` hook http://jsbin.com/cuzuxu/4/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Did not think of that. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Someone apparently wrote an ember-cli addon to address this

See the following SO answer [Ember sidebar - returning from "admin" sidebar to "normal"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727232/ember-sidebar-returning-from-admin-sidebar-to-normal)